# How do I disable Constant Weather in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having problems with the weather in Minecraft. The weather used to work normally, but for some reason, the weather won't change. Is there a way to fix it? Because the weather is on constant even when I turn off Constant Weather. I just want to have the normal weather cycle.

Comment: "even when I turn off Constant Weather" What do you mean by that? Sounds like you're using mods, in that case please tell us which ones.

Comment: I have the World Handler mod.

Comment: I updated my answer to include something about that mod. You may want to check it out. Edit: nevermind, you already disabled this constant weather according to your description.

Answer (score 4):

The game has a gamerule called: doWeatherCycle. If you set this gamerule to true, you get normal weather.

```
/gamerule doWeatherCycle true
```

EDIT:
I just noticed your comment about using the world handler mod. According to [this](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/world-handler-command-gui) webpage, you have to disable constant weather in the mod options. I suppose you know what that means.

EDIT:
You already disabled this option. Maybe your mod is installed incorrectly? You could try reinstalling it.

Comment: I'm on Minecraft 1.10.2 and that version of the game doesn't have that gamerule. :(

Comment: Why do you play in 1.10.2?

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command:

```
/weather clear 1000000
```

That stops rain, snow and thunderstorm for the next 277 hours, which should be enough.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you enter 10 million or 1 million? I first wrote 10 million, but then I noticed that it doesn't work. Use 1 million (1000000) instead.